# Почему generic -и не съедают примитивные типы

Tags: java

```
Abc<int> //ошибка
```

p.s. И ещё, как их по русски называть? Генэрик(и)?

Comment: я когда то на хэшкоде писал ответ на этот вопрос - просто создатели java немного поленились и не сделали. А ведь никто не мешал, кроме лени. Просто появился бы чуть расширенный boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это ограничение Java.

Дело в том, что для [type erasure](/questions/264255) тип-параметр при компиляции заменяется на `Object`. Но `int` не есть `Object`, поэтому такое запрещено.

Вы, однако, можете обойти запрет, использовав `Abc<Integer>`.

---

По поводу русскоязычного названия, в предыдущем вопросе использовалось слово «дженерики». Звучит не очень, да.

Comment: В дополнение к ответу: 

 что касается названия их по-русски -  их давным-давно зовут дженериками, исходя из очевидных правил транскрипции английских слов (буква g перед e, i, y  читается как "дж", а не "г". В редких случаях это правило нарушается (give, get, gift)). В С++ подобные типы называют шаблонами, но это ннесколько иное

Comment: В книге Шилдта они называются обобщенными типами или обобщениями

Comment: >В книге Шилдта они называются обобщенными типами или обобщениями

Справедливости ради Герберт Шилдт - это американский автор. Стало быть, пишет он на великом и могучем английском языке, а все русскоязычные названия есть результат работы переводчика. Следовательно, вряд ли это присуще сугубо книге Шилдта.

Comment: >В книге Шилдта они называются обобщенными типами или обобщениями

Справедливости ради Герберт Шилдт - это американский автор. Стало быть, пишет он на великом и могучем английском языке, а все русскоязычные названия есть результат работы переводчика. Следовательно, вряд ли это присуще сугубо книге Шилдта. Но вообще соглашусь - "обобщения" звучат вполне неплохо

Answer (score 1):

По-русски устоялось "дженерик" в разговорной речи или, более формально, "обобщенный тип".
Причину указали выше: стирание типов.

Для использования коллекций притимивных типов можно использовать стороннюю библиотеку [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/).