# Почему временный объект нельзя присвоить неконстантной ссылке?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Почему в стандарте языка сказано, что временный объект нельзя присвоить неконстантной ссылке?

Comment: В каком смысле "почему"? Потому что так сказано в стандарте языка. Или вас интересует "почему" так сказано в стандарте языка?

Comment: @AnT: Думаю, да. Мотивация стандарта всегда интересна.

Comment: А за что минус? Вопрос адекватный.

Comment: Я поставил минус, т.к. а) вопрос не по адресу(о чем написал alexolut) б) не вижу никакого подтверждения того, что Stanislav Petrov искал информацию в других источниках. Т.е. для меня это вопрос - растолкуйте мне почему так, а не иначе, а то мне лень самому ответ искать(не думаю что найти вопрос, на который ссылается Ant или похожий было бы большой проблемой). Если бы автор расширил свой вопрос приводя примеры найденных ответов, прося прояснить аспект - другое дело. Соседний [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759210/вспомогательный-класс-auto-ptr-ref#759260) из этой-же серии.

Comment: Для меня SO в первую очередь ресурс для поиска вопросов на конкретные, практические вопросы или же как справочное пособие в виде хорошо проработанных вопросов и ответов. А вопросы,где работа автора не видна лично я рассматриваю как неуважение к сообществу, бесплатно вкладывающегося в то, чтобы делать жизнь людей лучше, упрощая поиск, делясь опытом, уча в конце концов и экономя самое важное - время.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вступление: вопросы из разряда «почему так сделали в Стандарте» обычно закрывают на enSO, так как ответить могут только члены из комитета по стандартизации, которые принимали это правило, а они, как правило, не присутствуют на SO, чтобы дать ответ. Но данному вопросу повезло, его закрыли по другой причине (дубликат) и после публикации ответов, [один из которых](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827042/3240681) я и заимствую.

Если бы привязка временного объекта была возможна к неконстантной ссылки, могли бы возникать довольно странные ситуации. Например:

```
void inc(double& x)
{ x += 0.1; }

int i = 0;
inc(i);
```

Исходно переменная имеет тип `int`, но приходит в функцию как ссылка на `double`. Здесь создаётся временный объект, модификация которого внутри функции, реально ни к чему не приводит. Более того, она нелепа, так как осуществляется попытка увеличить целое на `0.1`, что, понятно дело, не является возможным.

Comment: Ну, я довольно много отвечаю на вопросы вида «почему так в Стандарте» (если сам знаю), хотя в комитетах не состою.

Comment: Этот пример скорее показывает, что разрешать неявные преобразования - не особо хорошая идея.

Comment: @VladD дело в том, как люди их интерпретируют, вот у меня был вопрос в прошлом году на enSO. Обратите внимание на его [эволюцию](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41359232/revisions).

Comment: @VTT требовать явных преобразований везде — тоже не лучший выход. Хотя предупреждения при потере точности, безусловно, полезны.

Comment: Ну от чего же? При наличии только явных преобразований жизнь сильно упрощается. Единственное имеющее смысл неявное преобразование - это приведение дочернего класса к родительскому. Но это скорее интерпретация отношения "is a" чем преобразование.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну вот вопросы у нас: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/351233/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581068/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/265034/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584353/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621082/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/239051/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543158/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582424/10105 — по-моему, они все хорошие.

Comment: @VTT я к тому, что это будет утомительно. Вот, например, функция `int f()` и мы хотим присвоить результат вещественной переменной `double d = f()`. Придется выполнять дополнительный обвес [различного рода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726774/176217), а это лишние телодвижения как-никак.

Comment: @VTT тем более, даже если преобразование будет явным для примера в ответе, то это ничего не изменит, преобразованный объект так и останется временным. Я о случае `inc(static_cast<double>(i))`.

Comment: А я к тому, что утомительно *без* этого. Отсутствие необходимости производить преобразования явно предоставляет дополнительные возможности для появления в коде дефектов преобразований типов, а даже при отсутствии дефектов маскирует потенциальные проблемы с выбором подходящих типов. Тут я имею ввиду, что сейчас код, содержащий массу неявных преобразований может выглядеть безобидно и не привлекать к себе внимания, а выявление дефектов преобразования и проблем с выбором подходящих типов требует на пару порядков больше усилий, чем написание явных преобразований.

Comment: Что касается возникновения "странных ситуаций", то при необходимости всегда осуществлять преобразования типов явно они возникать не могли бы, и приведенный вами пример приводил бы к ошибке компиляции даже без запрещения привязывания временного объекта к неконстантной ссылке. Собственно и запрещать эту привязку было бы незачем, так как временные объекты можно было бы создавать только явно.

Answer (score 2):

Это касается lvalue-reference.
rvalue-reference может быть не const.

Вырезка из стандарта C++ (N3691):

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> ...
>
> — Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.

[Example:

```
double& rd2 = 2.0;//error: not an lvalue and reference not const
int i = 2;
double& rd3 = i;//error: type mismatch and reference not const
```

— end example ]

Comment: Эм.. И какой вывод?